# Hook Problem in Wordpress Plugin - Inside Class

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a wordpress plugin. I wanted to send an admin notification when the first job plugin was activated.

However, when I try to do it with the codes I use below, although the function is called when the plugin is activated, the notification does not appear.

I guess I'm doing something wrong.

The function seems to be triggering but the notification is not reflecting.

```php
/**
 * Plugin Name: TFT
 * Version: 1.0.0
 */
 
 
defined('ABSPATH') or die("You can't access this file directly.");

define('TFT_PATH',plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));

define('TFT_FILE',__FILE__);

require __DIR__ . '/tft_init.php';

$tft = new TFT();
```

```php
class TFT
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        
        register_activation_hook(TFT_FILE,array($this,'activate'));
       
        
    }

    public function activate()
    {
        add_action('admin_notices',array($this,'activate_notice'));

    }

    public function activate_notice()
    {
        echo '<div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p>Thanks for installing TFT.</p>
        </div>';
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`register_activation_hook` will not work as you expected. I am a developer of many WP plugins and the only solution is to do the following:

```
class TFT
{
    private function __construct()
    {
        if( get_transient('tft_run_notification') ) {
            add_action('admin_notices',array($this,'activate_notice'));
            delete_transient('tft_run_notification');
        }
    }
    
    public function activate_notice()
    {
        echo '<div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p>Thanks for installing TFT.</p>
        </div>';
    }
    
    public static function register_activation() {
        register_activation_hook(TFT_FILE, function () {
            set_transient('tft_run_notification', 1, MINUTE_IN_SECONDS);
        });
    }
    
    protected static $init;
    public static function init() {
        
        if( !self::$init ) {
            self::$init = new self();
        }
    
        return self::$init;
    }
}
```

Then call this static object in the main plugin PHP file before all your code.

```
// Register activation hook
TFT::register_activation();
// Run the plugin
TFT::init();
```

`register_activation_hook` works quite differently and simply won't fire if you call it the standard OOP way. It must be called directly and preferably before any of your custom code. You can also do the same with `register_deactivation_hook`.

Also, these two functions MUST NOT be included in any filter or action.

One more thing, the `admin_notices` won't work inside `register_activation_hook` function. That's why you have to deal with transients.

Comment: It fires in the code given in the example, but ? Notification just doesn't work.

Comment: I just update my answer and give you exact solution